# Word boundary or digit in regex set

Tags: regex

I am scanning some US address data that could take the formats:

```
VA55452
VA 55452
55452VA
55452 VA
```

I have a regex to look for this, which is:

```
(?:[\b\d]VA[\b\d])
```

This does not return any matches at all, however:

```
(?:\bVA\b)
```

...would return matches for records 2 and 4, but not 1 and 3. Why is my first regex not working? It looks correct syntax wise to my eyes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex can work:

```
(?:\b|\d)VA(?:\b|\d)
```

You cannot use `\b` in a character class as **word boundary** as inside character class it will be treated as literal text.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pD7bX6/1)

Comment: hi there, thanks for the response. that now works as i need it to. thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `\b` into the character class. `\b` will loose it's special meaning of matching a word boundary inside the character class.

```
(?:\b|\d)VA(?:\b|\d)
```